# Get from java hashmap based on 2d distance

Tags: java, android, search, dictionary

I am making a strategy game in android with lots of units and I have come to a point where I need to check the position of every single object against every other one to see if the two are close enough together that they should start fighting. Right now the only way I can determine if two units are close enough is in this method:

```
public boolean inProximity(float x2, float y2) {
        return Math.sqrt((x2 - x) * (x2 - x) + (y2 - y) * (y2 - y)) <= proximityRadius;
    }
```

I don't want to be iterating through all the units an n-squared amount of times. I was looking at a TreeMap to store the positions, but then how would I (if it's even possible) get the keys based of distance from a unit?

Comment: Hashmap won't work.  TreeMap won't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to reconsider the data structure here and take a look at quadtrees. They essentially allow you to partition 2D space and do collision detections which seems to be your use case.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree

Just doing a google on java quadtree produces some hits on implementations. I haven't used any of them so I can't really vouch for them, but that should give you something to go on.

Answer (score 2):

1) As a first thing to think about, you don't need to take the square root. The square and the square root both increase as the numbers increase, so that would be one optimization.

2) This is known as the 'Closest Pair' problem, and there are divide-and-conquer based algorithms to solve it.

Take a look at: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closest_pair_of_points_problem

Comment: This is not quite the problem I am having, I don't need the closest points, but all points that are closer that x distance from each other.